# how to specify a url for a default image in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am using this code for assinging a default image for a post if user doesn't upload any. It works fine for home page. But when I go to detailed view of this post django looks image in 'domain/post/id/media/default-book.jpg' address. This is my code

```
{% if object.allCovers.all%}
    {% for cover in object.allCovers.all %}
        <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} 
        active {% endif %}">
            <img class="d-block w-100 cover-img" src="{{ 
            cover.covers.url }}" alt="First slide">
        </div>  
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <img class="cover-img" src="media/default-book.jpg" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

instead of address for the default image, how can i assign a url like {{ default.url }} this for the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
  <img class="cover-img" src="{% static 'default-book.jpg'%}">
```

and you should add

```
{% load static %}
```

to the top of your template